# Spark: How to save array as two column CSV?

Tags: arrays, csv, apache-spark

I've got an array with `predictions` and `labels` from logistic regression which looks like this:

```
labelAndPreds: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double, Double)] =  
MapPartitionsRDD[517] at map at <console>:52

scala> labelAndPreds.collect()
res2: Array[(Double, Double)] = Array((0.004106564139257318, 0.0), 
(0.3641478408865635, 0.0), (0.9999258409695498, 1.0), (0.342287288060...
```

How can I save it on local disk in `CSV` format with two columns (one for labels and one for predictions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.implicits._

val df = labelsAndPreds.toDF("labels", "predictions")

df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("labelsAndPreds.csv")
```